# WHERE clause with LIKE on multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT ci.cid, ci.set, ci.year, ci.name, ci.cardvar, ci.comp, ci.grade, ci.pop, ci.cardnum
      FROM uc
      INNER JOIN ci ON uc.cid = ci.cardId
      WHERE uc.uid = '$userId' and ci.name like '%$updateSearchCriteria%'
```

I would to include the `'updateSearchCriteria'` with other rows. So right now, if a user types on a persons name, it will look for only those names in the `name` row and return it.

So if `updateSearchCriteria` was bill -> all of bill will return.

I would like for a user to type in a `year`, `name`, or even `cardvar`.

```
SELECT ci.cid, ci.set, ci.year, ci.name, ci.cardvar, ci.comp, ci.grade, ci.pop, ci.cardnum
      FROM uc
      INNER JOIN ci ON uc.cid = ci.cardId
      WHERE uc.uid = '$userId' and ci.year like '%$updateSearchCriteria%' or 
          ci.name like '%$updateSearchCriteria%' or 
          ci.cardvar like '%$updateSearchCriteria%'
```

So now if I type in 2018 bill -> nothing returns.
or 2018 bill base (base being the cardvar) nothing will return. Maybe I need to combine everything in another column? Not sure.

How can I combine multiple rows to a where/like clause?

Answer (score 1):

You should add braces to force particular operator precedence and use separate search criteria for each column:

```sql
WHERE 
  uc.uid = '$userId' 
  AND 
  (
    ci.year LIKE '%$yearBeingSearched%' 
    OR
    ci.name LIKE '%$nameBeingSearched%'
    OR
    ci.cardvar LIKE '%$cardvarBeingSearched%'
  )
```

Comment: I was afraid of needing a separate search criteria. At the end of the day, i can defiantly change the client code if needed. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use CONCAT() function if you have different column with the same criteria:

```
WHERE uc.uid = '$userId' AND concat(ci.year, ci.name, ci.cardvar) like '%$cardvarBeingSearched%'
```

You can add more columns to the CONCAT() function as you like.

Answer (score -1):

You can split your criteria with spaces and use like statement for every split string. In this case you need to create a dynamic query

Comment: this is pointless without an example. but thank you.